# Jest + Svelte code coverage basic project

Tags: jestjs, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-jester

I started a new project provided by SvelteKit and added svelte-jester. I am able to run the code and tests but I get an odd coverage problem. The Header component has an SVG file which shows up as an uncovered branch and I'm not sure how to address it.

```
// Header.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import logo from './svelte-logo.svg';
</script>

<header>
    <div class="corner">
        <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">
            <img src={logo} alt="SvelteKit" />
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

```
// Header.test.js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte'

import Header from '../Header.svelte';

test('shows proper heading when rendered', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(Header);

    expect(getByText('Corner')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Coverage:
[image: missing coverage on branch]

Wondering if anyone else has had this issue and solved it. There is no branch here and logo is not a prop. How do I get test coverage for the `src`?

Jest Config for reference:

```
export default {
    bail: false,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/jest'],
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 80,
            functions: 80,
            lines: 80,
            statements: 80
        }
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "svelte", "ts"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(svg)$": "<rootDir>/src/jest/mock.js",
        "^\\$src(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src$1",
        "^\\$lib(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/lib$1",
        "^\\$app(.*)$": [
            "<rootDir>/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/app$1",
            "<rootDir>/.svelte-kit/build/runtime/app$1"
        ]
    },
    preset: "ts-jest",
    roots: ["<rootDir>/src/",],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.svelte$": [
            "svelte-jester", {
                "preprocess": true
            }
        ],
        "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest"
    },
    // transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect",
        './src/jest/setup.js'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The developers of Svelte say they won't fix this issue before version 4.

See this comment on their bug tracker: [Improve source map support for code coverage tools](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/8269#issuecomment-1441259788)